is it possible to handle webgl errors gracefully?
In Webgl is there a way of "catching" errors in the same way as you might do this in a CPU focussed language?
I'm specifically having a problem where my whole browser is crashing our before i can get to the terminal so I cant even see the error (i already know what the cause is but it would be good to somehow catch it).
for example in javascript i might do a try{}catch(e){/*do something*/}
I have also tried if(gl_PointCoord.z){/*only perform code if z doesnt crash me out*/}
and trying to set a variable but in each case it just dimps a million errors into the console and my browser collapses.

If your whole browser is crashing you've got a bigger problem. Try launching the browser from the command line. Sometimes it outputs more info that way. Also, file a bug with the browser vendor and a tiny repo.
